# Run a command without entry point

Tags: docker

How can I run a command against a container and tell docker not to run the entry point? e.g.

`docker-compose run  foo bash`

The above will run the entry point of the foo machine. How to prevent it temporarily without modifying Dockerfile?

Answer (score 3):

```
docker-compose run --entrypoint=bash foo bash
```

It'll run a nested bash, a bit useless, but you'll have your prompt.

Comment: You can actually omit the `bash` command: `docker-compose run --entrypoint=bash foo` should work, as well. Then, he can either attach to it or run an arbitrary command.

Comment: Thanks for the precision @MarcAndréFreiheit, guessed so but didn't took the time to test

Answer (score 2):

If you control the image, consider moving the entire default command line into the `CMD` instruction.  Docker [concatenates the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` together](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) when running a container, so you can do this yourself at build time.

```sh
# Bad: prevents operators from running any non-Python command
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["myapp.py"]

# Better: allows overriding command at runtime
CMD ["python", "myapp.py"]
```

This is technically "modifying the Dockerfile" but it won't change the default operation of your container: if you don't specify `entrypoint:` or `command:` in the `docker-compose.yml` then it will run the exact same command, but it also allows running things like debug shells in the way you're trying to.

I tend to reserve `ENTRYPOINT` for two cases.  There's a common pattern of using an `ENTRYPOINT` to do some first-time setup (*e.g.*, running database migrations) and then `exec "$@"` to run whatever was passed as `CMD`.  This preserves the semantics of `CMD` (your `docker-compose run bash` will still work, but migrations will happen first).  If I'm building a `FROM scratch` or other "distroless" image where it's actually impossible to run other commands (there isn't a `/bin/sh` at all) then making the single thing in the image be the `ENTRYPOINT` makes sense.